# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/css/sac/Condition

Tags: apache-flex, noclassdeffounderror

It is the first time I am posting my question here (I used to find the answer anywhere but this is turning me crazy). For my new job I need to use FlashBuilder (Adobe) to program in Flex. My partners are using Windows 8, but the enterprise computer they gave me is running Windows 10 already. I followed step by step the same manual they used to install everything, but I am obtaining the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/css/sac/Condition
at flex2.tools.API.getCompilers(API.java:264)
at flex2.tools.oem.Application.recompile(Application.java:918)
at flex2.tools.oem.Application.compile(Application.java:681)
at flex2.tools.flexbuilder.BuilderApplication.compile(BuilderApplication.java:354)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASApplicationBuilder$MyBuilder.mybuild(ASApplicationBuilder.java:319)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASApplicationBuilder.build(ASApplicationBuilder.java:129)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASBuilder.build(ASBuilder.java:198)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASItemBuilder.build(ASItemBuilder.java:70)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.buildItem(FlexProjectBuilder.java:607)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.build(FlexProjectBuilder.java:382)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexIncrementalBuilder.build(FlexIncrementalBuilder.java:187)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.css.sac.Condition
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.sdks.FlexClassLoader.loadClass(FlexClassLoader.java:133)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
... 23 more
```

I tried to install next plug-in: org.w3c.css.sac.source_1.3.1.v200903091627.jar, but I didn't achieve anything. I tried to search in the internet but I can't find a solution. We are thinking that the problem is about the operative system, so it is the unique difference between their enviroments and mine.

If you already had this error or you know any solution I would be really thankful.

Thank you very much,
Juan.

Comment: Is this when you're trying to launch FlashBuilder or when you're trying to compile?

Comment: It is when I am trying to compile. @Brian

Comment: Are you using the default Flex SDK included with FlashBuilder?  For that matter, are you using Flashbuilder as a standalone install or as a plugin to an Eclipse installation?

Comment: It is an standalone installation, version 4.6. I am using SDK 3.5, I added it appart because it doesn't appear by default with this Flash Builder version, but I need to use it due to the project in which I am working was programmed for that SDK version. @Brian